# How would I create a loop which splits up a string into different emails?

Tags: vb.net

It is pretty self explanatory. I would like to split Cc into emails using the ; as an indicator.The code I have at the moment is as follows:

```
Dim sEmailAddress As String



                Dim iPos As Integer
                iPos = InStr(Me.Cc, ";") ' Looks in the first parameter for the second parameter and returns the position of the first occurance of the second parameter. If there is no occurrance of the second parameter then 0 will be returned
                ' 
                Dim iLen As Integer
                iLen = Len(Me.Cc) ' iLen will = then length of me.CC - for example if me.cc = "Hello World", iLen = 11

                '
                Dim sPart As String
                sPart = Left(Me.Cc, 10) ' Returns the first 10 characters from Me.CC - for example if Me.CC = "Hello World", sPart = "Hello Wor"
                '
                Dim sPart2 As String
                sPart2 = Right(Me.Cc, 4) ' Returns the right most 4 characters from Me.CC, for example if me.CC = "Hello World", sPart2 = "orld"
                '
                Dim sPart3 As String
                sPart3 = Mid(Me.Cc, 6, 2) ' Returns 2 characters starting at position 6 from Me.CC, for example if me.cc = "Hello World", sPart3 = " W"

                Do While 


                    ' get email address
                    oNetworxEmail.AddToAddress(sEmailAddress)
                Loop
                If  Then
                    ' get email address
                    oNetworxEmail.AddToAddress(sEmailAddress)
                End If
```

Comment: Look at `String.Split()`.

Comment: I know about string.split. But I need to do it this way before I attempt split

Answer (score 0):

Thats a big headache if you wanna do it that way. String.split is a much better way.

```
Dim splitArray() As String = String.Split(Me.Cc, ";")
```