# How would I manipulate a string in order to create a set of emails?

Tags: vb.net

I have received in my Cc string which contains a string which separates emails using the ; character. I would like to know how to use the different VB functions to do this. I need to loop around the strings until there are no more ; characters in the code. And I would also like to add them to my object oNetworxEmail. But I think I know how to do this already as I have added some code already. Someone, please help. I really can't get my head around it

```
Dim sEmailAddress As String

Dim iPos As Integer
iPos = InStr(Me.Cc, ";") 

Dim iLen As Integer
iLen = Len(Me.Cc)

Dim sPart As String
sPart = Left(Me.Cc, 10) 

Dim sPart2 As String
sPart2 = Right(Me.Cc, 4) 

Dim sPart3 As String
sPart3 = Mid(Me.Cc, 6, 2) 

Do While iPos <> 0
    '???
    oNetworxEmail.AddToAddress(sEmailAddress)
Loop

If ??? Then
    '???
    oNetworxEmail.AddToAddress(sEmailAddress)
End If
```

Comment: Can't you just use String.Split ?

Comment: I forgot to mention, no I need to know how to use it this way

Comment: @TheFool why? homework? much easier with String.Split.

Comment: Yes, split is next on the agenda. Please can you help?

Comment: This [sounds familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927130/how-would-i-create-a-loop-which-splits-up-a-string-into-different-emails).  Maybe you two can work together? ;-)

Comment: @TheFool Using Split will reduce the number of bugs, building your own split function can introduce problems. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) has a very good sample. Also, instead of InStr/Len/Left/Right/Mid I would suggest you use the [methods in the string class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Mark LOL great find!

Comment: @Mark. Yes, that's me. The same person. Nobody responded and this is my home account. You want the truth? I'm at my first programming job and I feel like I'm drowning. So yes. I need help.

Comment: @the_lotus Thanks for your reply. However my senior developer does not want me to use split. He wants me to understand how to do it manually first. I have tried looking it up online, I understand the concept but dont know how to use it in a loop.

Comment: You may want to add an example value for `sEmailAddress` and what you are expecting as a result because I am having a hard time understanding your existing code, e.g. what the `sPart/2/3` variables are for.  Do you really just want to split a string on `;` characters without using `String.Split`, or are there some other restrictions in place?

Comment: You can use the `IL Disassembler` or `Red Gate Reflector` or just search the internet and see how `Split` is built and build it yourself ! :)

Comment: @Mark Thank you Mark. An example sEmailAddress would be example@hotmail.com. The Cc would be: example@hotmail.com;example2@gmail.com etc. Part 2/3 are variables for right and middle. I would like to split it everytime it discovers a ; and then gets that email address to the left. Once it has the email I would like it to move onto the next one. I can't use Split because my Senior developer wants me to understand this way of doing it first because otherwise I might not understand the split way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest you familiarize yourself with the .Net equivalents of InStr, Len, Left, Right and Mid as those are all legacy functions from old VB.

Second, I would delete your other question. It's quite frowned upon to ask the same question multiple times on this site.

Finally, here is the answer to your problem without using the split function:

```
    Dim nIndex1 As Int32 = 0    ' The substring function starts at zero so we begin here
    Dim nIndex2 As Int32 = Me.CC.Text.IndexOf(";")  ' Find the first semi-colon in the text

    ' Loop until there are no more semi-colons found

    Do Until nIndex2 = -1
        oNetworxEmail.AddToAddress(Me.CC.Text.Substring(nIndex1, nIndex2 - nIndex1))    ' Add an email address to the oNetworxEmail object

        nIndex1 = nIndex2 + 1   ' Set the first index to the position beyond the last semi-colon
        nIndex2 = Me.CC.Text.IndexOf(";", nIndex1)  ' Search for the next semi-colon beyond the last
    Loop

   ' Add the last email address in the event that there is no semi-colon at the end of the string

    If nIndex1 < Me.CC.Text.Length Then
        oNetworxEmail.AddToAddress(Me.CC.Text.Substring(nIndex1, Me.CC.Text.Length - nIndex1))
    End If
```

**Update:** The code has been updated to support a string which does not have a semi-colon at the end of the text.

Comment: Thank you very much and okay, I will do. Thank you so much. I understand this too!

Comment: Also if this works for you please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark beside the answer and it will turn green. This will let others know you already found the answer to your question and no longer require help on this issue.

Comment: I think this may miss the last entry if there is no final `;` character.

Comment: I don't think it will work if there is just one email

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. The code has been updated to address these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you could do it by looping through the characters, one at a time.

```
' Code assumes that Option Infer On
Dim sEmailAddress = "; joe@bob.com;harry@windsor.com;; barack@whitehouse.gov ; ;"
' A list to hold the separate email addresses
Dim emails = New List(Of String)()
' A string builder used to build up the current email address
Dim currentEmail = New StringBuilder()
' Loop through each character in the source string
For Each c In sEmailAddress
    Select Case c
        Case ";"c
            ' We found the delimiter.  If the current email is not empty
            ' then we will add it to the list.
            If currentEmail.Length > 0 Then
                emails.Add(currentEmail.ToString())
            End If
            ' Clear out the buffer for the next email
            currentEmail.Clear()
        Case " "c
            ' We will ignore spaces, since they aren't valid in an email address
        Case Else
            ' Append the current character to the current email address
            currentEmail.Append(c)
    End Select
Next
' Add the last email address to the list, if any
If currentEmail.Length > 0 Then
    emails.Add(currentEmail.ToString())
End If
```

At this point `emails` will have the split email addresses:

```
joe@bob.com
harry@windsor.com
barack@whitehouse.gov
```

You can just loop over them to do what you want (you could integrate this into the above code, if you wanted):

```
For Each email In emails
    oNetworxEmail.AddToAddress(email)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. I appreciate the time which you put it. It really does help me because I can make sense of it once I see it and can then do it myself. I'll give the String.Split a go myself tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

Update: Example of why how things are done matters. These are rough processing time on these string manipulation answers (after upping the email count to ~800)

My ghetto answer: **230ms**

Joey Joe Joe Jr Shabadoo's answer: **120ms**

Mark's answer: **65ms**

In short, don't use my method. Heh.

---

By no means is this better than the others' answers I don't think. Just another example of going through an array or set of objects using basic checks. String.Append would probably be better. I honestly don't know the speed differences.

Another (more ghetto) way of doing it for perspective...

```
Dim sCC As String = "one@two.com;three@four.net;five@six.gov"
Dim nStartPos As Integer = 0
Dim nEndPos As Integer = 0
Dim bStarted As Boolean = False
Dim lstEmails As New List(Of String)

Try
    For i As Integer = 0 To sCC.Length
        If bStarted Then
            bStarted = False
            nStartPos = i
        End If   

        'Using OrElse here, because I don't want it evaluating sCC(i) at sCC.Length
        If i = sCC.Length OrElse sCC(i) = ";" Then
            nEndPos = i
        End If

        If nEndPos <> 0 Then
            lstEmails.Add(sCC.Substring(nStartPos, nEndPos - nStartPos))
            nStartPos = nEndPos
            nEndPos = 0
            bStarted = True
        End If
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try

For j As Integer = 0 To lstEmails.Count - 1
    MessageBox.Show(lstEmails(j))
Next
```

Only had to use methods Substring, Add, Length, and Count. Substring could been avoided as well, but it'd get messier.

p.s. Avoid using old VB functions like "Mid" and "Left". There are newer .NET equivalents that you should be using instead.