# Out of range exception while string manipulation

Tags: vb.net

I have created a Do While loop which will split a string into emails and then send an email to those users. At the moment In the string I only have three emails. I am doing the old fashioned VB way of doing it using Instr, Left and Len. I **cannot** use Split String as I need to get this way to work first. Basically on the second loop, it does not remove the email address which has just gone through the loop. However on the loop before(there are only 3 at the moment) it does remove the email address. After which it gets to creating another substring and then throws the Out of range except. It includes additional information that states the Index and length must refer to a location within the string. However, I would have thought that they do, considering it worked on the first attempt. The code is as follows:

```
Dim sEmailAddress As String

Dim iPos As Integer
iPos = InStr(Me.Cc, ";") 

Dim iLen As Integer
iLen = Len(Me.Cc) 

Dim iRemainingLength As Integer = 0

Do While iPos <> 0

    sEmailAddress = Left(Me.Cc, iPos - 1)

    oNetworxEmail.AddToAddress(sEmailAddress)

    iRemainingLength = iLen - (iPos)




    Me.Cc = Me.Cc.Substring(iPos, iRemainingLength)
    iPos = InStr(Me.Cc, ";")
Loop

If iRemainingLength > 0 Then
  oNetworxEmail.AddToAddress(Me.Cc)
End If
```

Comment: `Instr` will return -1 when not found. since -1 <> 0, your loop continues when it should not

Comment: @Plutonix The legacy Instr function returns a one-based index if the string is found, or zero if it is not found. I believe the problem is caused by not updating iLen when the cc string is shortened.

Comment: Why don't you use the answer from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929541/how-would-i-manipulate-a-string-in-order-to-create-a-set-of-emails)?

Comment: Figured it out myself. Sorry, couldn't get my head around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you think you can't use String.Split to do this. You certainly can, and in my opinion it is the best way to accomplish the task. Still, if you insist on doing it this way, the exception is caused by the fact that you are removing items from the cc string but you never update the length of the string that you stored in iLen outside the loop. Here is a version that should work. Note that I also use the current .Net string methods and also use Trim to remove any blanks that may be between the e-mail addresses.

```
Do While Me.cc.Contains(";")
    Dim iPos As Integer = Me.cc.IndexOf(";"c)
    oNetworxEmail.AddToAddress(Me.cc.Substring(0, iPos).Trim)
    Me.cc = Me.cc.Substring(iPos + 1)
Loop
oNetworxEmail.AddToAddress(Me.cc.Trim)
```

**I do not recommend using this code, instead, I recommend using String.Split as you have been advised before.**

[Edit]
Here is how I would code this using String.Split

```
For Each addr As String In Me.cc.Split(";"c)
    oNetworxEmail.AddToAddress(addr.Trim)
Next
```